Use of Closedness in Proving Hausdorff Metric's Triangle Inequality
I am working through Sidney Morris's Topology without Tears. In particular, I'm working on exercise 6.1.16, which asks us to verify that Hausdorff distance is a metric on the set of all closed bounded subsets of a metric space. In my proof of the triangle inequality, I make use of the boundedness of the subsets but I do not see where I am relying on closedness. I think this means there's a gap in my reasoning or that I am implicitly relying on closedness somewhere, but in either case I don't see where. Why is closedness required for the Hausdorff metric?
The following is my proof of the triangle inequality for the Hausdorff metric:
\begin{align}
d_{H}(A,C)&=\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{c\in C}d(a,c),\sup_{c\in C}\inf_{a\in A}d(a,c)\right\} \\&\leq\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{c\in C}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right),\sup_{c\in C}\inf_{a\in A}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right)\right\} \;(\forall b)
\end{align}
So, in particular,
\begin{align}
d_{H}(A,C)&\leq\inf_{b\in B}\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{c\in C}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right),\sup_{c\in C}\inf_{a\in A}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right)\right\} \\&=\max\left\{ \inf_{b\in B}\sup_{a\in A}\inf_{c\in C}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right),\inf_{b\in B}\sup_{c\in C}\inf_{a\in A}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right)\right\} \\&=\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B}\inf_{c\in C}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right),\sup_{c\in C}\inf_{b\in B}\inf_{a\in A}\left(d(a,b)+d(b,c)\right)\right\} \\&=\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b)+\inf_{b\in B}\inf_{c\in C}d(b,c),\inf_{b\in B}\inf_{a\in A}d(a,b)+\sup_{c\in C}\inf_{b\in B}d(b,c)\right\} \\&\leq\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b)+\sup_{b\in B}\inf_{c\in C}d(b,c),\sup_{b\in B}\inf_{a\in A}d(a,b)+\sup_{c\in C}\inf_{b\in B}d(b,c)\right\} \\&\leq\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b)+d_{H}(B,C),\sup_{b\in B}\inf_{a\in A}d(a,b)+d_{H}(B,C)\right\} \\&=\max\left\{ \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b),\sup_{b\in B}\inf_{a\in A}d(a,b)\right\} +d_{H}(B,C)\\&=d_{H}(A,B)+d_{H}(B,C)
\end{align}

Hint: Calculate the Hausdorff distance between the (origin-centered) open and closed unit disks in the Euclidean line $\mathbb{E}^1$ say.

(This is already pointed out in the comment, but let me just put an answer here). You are correct that in the proof of the triangle inequality, the closedness of the subsets $A, B$ are not necessary. Indeed, one can show
$$\tag{1} d_H (A, C) = d_H (\bar A, \bar C).$$
for any bounded subsets $A, C$. Equation (1) also tells you what goes wrong when you consider subsets that are not closed: one has
$$ d_H(A, \bar A) = d_H(\bar A, \bar A) = 0.$$
Hence if there is a bounded subset $A$ in your metric space such that $A \neq \bar A$, then $d_H (A, \bar A) = 0$ although $A\neq \bar A$. This violates the definition of a metric.
